# Excel - Conditionally format one table based on another table

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a database, where in one column I have the information about if the data was revised or not.

[image]

I then have a table that I have built using index/match, to have the data presented as desired.

However, I have tried unsuccessfully to conditionally format the data on the table, so that in case the column "Was revised?" is "Yes", it would show the value in red, as shown below.

Have you ever done anything similar? Did you use a formula in conditional formatting on VBA?

Thank you!

Comment: You can use conditional formatting with a rule based on COUNTIFS but if you're dealing with lots of data it may bog the workbook down.

Comment: In the conditional formatting you can use a similar formula to the INDEX/MATCH you used to get the GDP values, but instead of returning the GDP values you return the values from the 'Revised' column, and if 'Yes' is returned format the cell appropriately. I would post formulas but I've no idea how your data is set out.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest converting your data into Excel Tables first. The easiest thing would be using Conditional Formatting in Excel.
However, if you convert your data into Tables, you can write a Macro to highlighted the cells red when the update column says "Yes"